# Use an Android emulator image on multiple machines

Tags: android, emulation

I've created a custom build of Android and got it running as an emulator image on the development machine.  I need to be able to use that image on another computer running Windows (it was built on the Mac).  I've found the image files that the emulator uses (ramdisk.img, userdata.img and system.img) but I'm not sure how to create a new target that I can access from the SDK and AVD manager.  Anybody have experience with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform the following steps:

> 1. Create a new AVD in AVD Manager with the version equal to your custor ROM.
> 2. Go to %userprofile%/.android/avd/your_avd_name.avd and substitute system.img with your built ROM
> 3. Run created AVD.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot I asked this question so long ago.  That is definitely the solution I've been using!

Comment: If you find the answer by yourself it worth to post it :) However, it's only one possible way to launch emulator. You can also use emulator command with parameters to test your image.

Comment: it was so long ago that I completely forgot I'd been looking for an answer! So you can have the points ;)

Comment: Thanks ) I try to reduce the number of unanswered questions )