# Creating new AVD for the newly built android system image

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have built android lollipop code and i have generated the system image. I would like to run this in a emulator on a different machine where android sdk latest version is installed. According to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457386/use-an-android-emulator-image-on-multiple-machines/27421514#27421514) I tried creating a new avd. And i tried going to the path (i.e. /.android/avd/your_avd_name.avd) , but icould not find the system.img file to substitute. What solution can I possibly use. Please let me know.

Regards,

Sathya Prasad P

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but, what's the use of creating your own system image? What's wrong with the images provided by Android through the SDK Manager? And why go into all that trouble?

Comment: @Leo . The default system images are working fine and also the i can emulate my built code in my system. But I would really like to know how to replace it with custom images and run it. By any chance do you know how to use it ?